# SQL Server localdb. Confusion about two MDF files

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, localdb

In my WPF/C# app, I recently installed localDB v.11 via nuget. Then I created a `.MDF` file in the root of my project.

When I run the app, the CRUD operations work fine, but they all are carried out on the database created in the `bin\debug` folder.

Nothing changes in my root `.MDF` file. Please guide, why is it happening?

Is there a way to store data in the actual `.MDF` file? Or am I getting the concept wrong. What happens if I make a release and use it on some other system?
My internet search lead me to many links which didn't answer my question.

Please also suggest some tutorial/book for using localdb.

Regards

Comment: This is a **Visual Studio** specific behavior (the copying of the `.mdf` to  `bin\debug`) - that won't happen on your client's PC's. To be totally safe, use a **full path** for your `.mdf` file in your connection string

Comment: Yep. A build configuration. Follow the discussion in this link. it helps :)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8d159b92-e081-48a4-b684-c7161b5a8e1e/how-to-deploy-localdb-database-with-wpf-app?forum=wpf

Comment: @marc_s, Thanks for the tip, Yes you are right about VS behaviour. I also figured out that changing property of my root DB file to "copy if newer" doesn't replace the build DB, and so i have my previous data. Pleae post it as an answer so that i can mark it....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This copying of the `.mdf` file to `bin\debug` upon execution of your application is a well-known Visual Studio specific behavior.

This will not happen on your client's PC's.

To be totally safe, use a full path for your `.mdf` file in your connection string.