# SqlException: Invalid object name 'service'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am working on getting up to speed with ASP.NET MVC for web development. I get the can't find object error,

> SqlException: Invalid object name 'service'

that seems to be common. I have verified that the table exists and the database exists and the table name doesn't have spaces before or after it. I have access to the database or I would get another error.

In my service class I use the table classifier to tell the system the actual table name as below.

```cs
[Table ("service")]
public class service
{
    [Key]
    public int service_id { get; set; }
    public string service_name { get; set; }
    public string service_logo { get; set; }

    public int externalcontacts_id { get; set; }
    public int classification_id { get; set; }
}
```

The error happens when I try to access the database to get live data to pass to my view. I have tried more formal LINQ queries but regardless of what I do I get the same error. The current code that generates it is as below.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var serviceList = await (_context.Services).ToListAsync();

    return View(serviceList);
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. I can see the database in the Server Explorer and access the data but I can't access it from my app. I am not the DB administrator. Do they need to give privileges to my application? I don't know. I have never worked with SQL Server.

Comment: What are you using to access the data? Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes, Entity Famework.  I have patterned it after the MvcMovie database

Comment: `SqlException: Invalid object name` means, you are trying to query a table that does not exist. So if you see that table in the Server Explorer but cannot use it in your app, chances are high, that you are either 1) connecting to a different database or 2) connecting with a different user, who lacks priviledges. Are you connecting to a full SQL Server instance or are you using LocalDB. If the latter, have a look at the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231127/sql-server-localdb-confusion-about-two-mdf-files

Comment: I will look into it. I am using the same connection string as the one used by VS but I suppose it could be referencing a local copy. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your connection string?

Comment: Probably not. But it includes the server name, database name, login credentials. I was able to access the database using SQLConnection to determine the table names. I used the same connection string there. Maybe Entity Framework doesn't work with this? I would need to ask the IT people next week. Thanks

Comment: Are you using `AttachDbFilename` in the connection string? Are you connecting with Windows Authentication (`IntegratedSecurity/TrustedConnection`) but under a different Windows login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I had to add the schema name to the system.

Answer (score 0):

Could be you've got the wrong database, wrong schema, the database is case-sensitive, and you've got the case wrong, or you're connecting with the wrong user.  Query the catalog from your application code and see if you can see the table.  eg what does this return?

```
select quotename(schema_name(schema_id)) + '.' + quotename(name) table_name
from sys.tables  t
where t.name like '%service%' collate Latin1_General_CI_AI
```